# How to write shell script for finding number of pages in PDF?

Tags: shell, pdf

I am generating a PDF dynamically. How can I check the number of pages in the PDF using a shell script?

Comment: Only using builtin shell commands? Or do you "allow" external tools like e.g. pdftk or pdfinfo?

Comment: i m ok by any means but i need page number in a variable (shell script) so that i can pass this parameter to another function.

Comment: This question could be useful: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655478/bash-routine-to-return-the-page-number-of-a-given-line-number-from-text-file)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Without any extra package:

```
strings < file.pdf | sed -n 's|.*/Count -\{0,1\}\([0-9]\{1,\}\).*|\1|p' \
    | sort -rn | head -n 1
```

Using pdfinfo:

```
pdfinfo file.pdf | awk '/^Pages:/ {print $2}'
```

Using pdftk:

```
pdftk file.pdf dump_data | grep NumberOfPages | awk '{print $2}'
```

---

You can also recursively sum the total number of pages in all PDFs via pdfinfo as follows:

```
find . -xdev -type f -name "*.pdf" -exec pdfinfo "{}" ";" | \
    awk '/^Pages:/ {n += $2} END {print n}'
```

Comment: I found that the shell only method is not always reliable. I have PDF files with only one Page having several /Count in them wit different numbers. I suggest using one othe other two methods.

Comment: @Crami thanks for the info! Is it possible that you share at least one of these PDFs?

Comment: On Linux, **pdfinfo** (v0.12.4) does not print the correct number of pages: it says `12,052` while Adobe says `20,131`.  The first method, however, does report the same number as Adobe.

Comment: @ShipluMokaddim It *is* super hacky, but you don't need any additional packages

Comment: It's important to point out that the PDF count of pages may be affected by its inner objects compression. However, when it's not the case, the number of pages could be present after '.*/N' or '.*/Pages'. It's not trivial to find out which tag holds the correct value. But, the shell solution works well and is a great alternative to pdf's trailer dictionary search using pdfinfo

Comment: You can get the number of pages without the need of `awk` by using the `\K` operator of `grep`. The command to execute would be `pdfinfo file.pdf | grep -Po 'Pages:[[:space:]]+\K[[:digit:]]+'`.

Comment: Here's another one with `pdftoppm`, which comes pre-installed on Ubuntu: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66963293/4561887.

Comment: How does your `strings` solution work, by the way? Can you please explain it? I don't have any idea what is really contained in a PDF binary.

Comment: I tried ```strings < file.pdf | sed -n 's|.*/Count -\{0,1\}\([0-9]\{1,\}\).*|\1|p'``` for two-three files and it works fine. Why do we pipe it to ```sort -rn | head -n 1```

Answer (score 9):

The imagemagick library provides a tool called identify which in conjunction with counting the lines of output gets you what you are after...imagemagick is a easy install on osx with brew.

Here is a functional bash script that captures it to a shell variable and dumps it back to the screen...

```
#/bin/bash
pdfFile=$1
echo "Processing $pdfFile"
numberOfPages=$(/usr/local/bin/identify "$pdfFile" 2>/dev/null | wc -l | tr -d ' ')
#Identify gets info for each page, dump stderr to dev null
#count the lines of output
#trim the whitespace from the wc -l outout
echo "The number of pages is: $numberOfPages"
```

And the output of running it...

```
$ ./countPages.sh aSampleFile.pdf 
Processing aSampleFile.pdf
The number of pages is: 2
$
```

Comment: BTW: You should use `$()` instead of backticks `\`\`` see [BashFAQ/082](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

Answer (score 9):

The `pdftotext` utility converts a pdf file to text format inserting page breaks between the pages. (aka: form-feed characters `$'\f'` ):

```
NAME
       pdftotext - Portable Document Format (PDF) to text converter.

SYNOPSIS
       pdftotext [options] [PDF-file [text-file]]

DESCRIPTION
       Pdftotext converts Portable Document Format (PDF) files to plain text.

       Pdftotext  reads  the PDF file, PDF-file, and writes a text file, text-file.  If text-file is
       not specified, pdftotext converts file.pdf to file.txt.  If text-file is  ´-',  the  text  is
       sent to stdout.
```

There are many combinations to solve your problem, choose one of them:

1) pdftotext + grep:

`$ pdftotext file.pdf - | grep -c $'\f'`

2) pdftotext + awk (v1):

`$ pdftotext file.pdf - | awk 'BEGIN{n=0} {if(index($0,"\f")){n++}} END{print n}'`

3) pdftotext + awk (v2):

`$ pdftotext sample.pdf - | awk 'BEGIN{ RS="\f" } END{ print NR }'`

4)  pdftotext + awk (v3):

`$ pdftotext sample.pdf - | awk -v RS="\f" 'END{ print NR }'`

Hope it Helps!

Comment: WATCH OUT! These different lines might give back different numbers! 1 and 2 gave me 264 on a file, but 3 and 4 returned 286. Not sure about the exact reason.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a version for the command line directly (based on pdfinfo):

```
for f in *.pdf; do pdfinfo "$f" | grep Pages | awk '{print $2}'; done
```

Comment: I love this, thank you. Here the filename is printed to the right of the number of pages:
for f in *.pdf; do pdfinfo "$f" | grep Pages | awk '{printf $2 }'; echo " $f"; done

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: This one counts recursively in each folder and prints file name and # of pages. find -name "*.pdf" $1 | while read x; do pdfinfo "$x" | grep Pages | awk '{printf $2 }'; echo " $x"; done

Answer (score 5):

Here is a total hack using `pdftoppm`, which comes preinstalled on Ubuntu (tested on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 at least):

```
# for a pdf withOUT a password
pdftoppm mypdf.pdf -f 1000000 2>&1 | grep -o '([0-9]*)\.$' \
| grep -o '[0-9]*'

# for a pdf WITH a password which is `1234`
pdftoppm -upw 1234 mypdf.pdf -f 1000000 2>&1 | grep -o '([0-9]*)\.$' \
| grep -o '[0-9]*'
```

How does this work? Well, if you specify a `f`irst page which is larger than the pages in the PDF (I specify page number `1000000`, which is too large for all known PDFs), it will print the following error to `stderr`:

> Wrong page range given: the first page (1000000) can not be after the last page (142).

So, I pipe that `stderr` msg to `stdout` with `2>&1`, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16497456/4561887), then I pipe that to grep to match the `(142).` part with this regular expression (`([0-9]*)\.$`), then I pipe that to grep again with this regular expression (`[0-9]*`) to find just the number, which is `142` in this case. That's it!

### Wrapper functions and speed testing

Here are a couple wrapper functions to test these:

```
# get the total number of pages in a PDF; technique 1.
# See this ans here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14736593/4561887
# Usage (works on ALL PDFs--whether password-protected or not!):
#       num_pgs="$(getNumPgsInPdf "path/to/mypdf.pdf")"
# SUPER SLOW! Putting `time` just in front of the `strings` cmd shows it takes ~0.200 sec on a 142
# pg PDF!
getNumPgsInPdf() {
    _pdf="$1"

    _num_pgs="$(strings < "$_pdf" | sed -n 's|.*/Count -\{0,1\}\([0-9]\{1,\}\).*|\1|p' \
        | sort -rn | head -n 1)"

    echo "$_num_pgs"
}

# get the total number of pages in a PDF; technique 2.
# See my ans here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66963293/4561887
# Usage, where `pw` is some password, if the PDF is password-protected (leave this off for PDFs
# with no password):
#       num_pgs="$(getNumPgsInPdf2 "path/to/mypdf.pdf" "pw")"
# SUPER FAST! Putting `time` just in front of the `pdftoppm` cmd shows it takes ~0.020 sec OR LESS
# on a 142 pg PDF!
getNumPgsInPdf2() {
    _pdf="$1"
    _password="$2"

    if [ -n "$_password" ]; then
        _password="-upw $_password"
    fi

    _num_pgs="$(pdftoppm $_password "$_pdf" -f 1000000 2>&1 | grep -o '([0-9]*)\.$' \
        | grep -o '[0-9]*')"

    echo "$_num_pgs"
}
```

Testing them with the `time` command in front shows that the `strings` one is extremely slow, taking **~0.200 sec** on a 142 pg pdf, whereas the `pdftoppm` one is very fast, taking **~0.020 sec or less** on the same pdf. The `pdfinfo` technique in Ocaso's answer below is also very fast--the same as the `pdftoppm` one.

### See also

1. [These awesome answers by Ocaso Protal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14736593/4561887).
2. These functions above will be used in my `pdf2searchablepdf` project here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/PDF2SearchablePDF.

Comment: This is light years faster than pdftk, important if you are calling this on a lot of PDFs on a dynamic web page. This is the best solution, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

mupdf/mutool solution:

```sh
mutool info tmp.pdf | grep '^Pages' | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Just dug out an old script (in ksh) I found:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh
# Usage: pdfcount.sh file.pdf
#
# Optimally, this would be a mere:
#       pdfinfo file.pdf | grep Pages | sed 's/[^0-9]*//'

[[ "$#" != "1" ]] && {
   printf "ERROR: No file specified\n"
   exit 1
}

numpages=0
while read line; do
   num=${line/*([[:print:]])+(Count )?(-)+({1,4}(\d))*([[:print:]])/\4}
   (( num > numpages)) && numpages=$num
done < <(strings "$@" | grep "/Count")
print $numpages
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're on macOS you can query pdf metadata like this:

```
mdls -name kMDItemNumberOfPages -raw file.pdf
```

as seen here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225175/get-number-of-pdf-pages-in-terminal

Answer (score 2):

Another mutool solution making better use of the options:

`mutool show file.pdf Root/Pages/Count`

Answer (score 1):

I made a few improvement in [Marius Hofert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704274/how-to-write-shell-script-for-finding-number-of-pages-in-pdf/54279233#54279233) tip to sum the returned values.

```
for f in *.pdf; do pdfinfo "$f" | grep Pages | awk '{print $2}'; done | awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}'
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I suspect that the reason your answer is receiving negative attention is that it would have been better left as a comment on the answer you reference.

Comment: Yes, I know. The problem is I am new here, and stackoverflow only allows to comment with 50 reputation score. I still don't have that.

Answer (score 0):

To build on Marius Hofert's answer, this command uses a bash for loop to show you the number of pages, display the filename, and it will ignore the case of the file extension.

```
for f in *.[pP][dD][fF]; do pdfinfo "$f" | grep Pages | awk '{printf $2 }'; echo " $f"; done
```

Comment: I think the use of both `grep` and `awk` in a pipeline is a bit of an overdo, it's better to use `awk` solely, which reduces the pipe count by one. Also, use `shopt -s nocaseglob` to ignore the file extension's case instead of entering every capital letter manually.