# bash routine to return the page number of a given line number from text file

Tags: bash, shell, ascii, text-processing

Consider a plain text file containing page-breaking ASCII control character "Form Feed" ($'\f'):

```
alpha\n
beta\n
gamma\n\f
one\n
two\n
three\n
four\n
five\n\f
earth\n
wind\n
fire\n
water\n\f
```

Note that each page has a random number of lines.

Need a bash routine that return the page number of a given line number from a text file containing page-breaking ASCII control character.

After a long time researching the solution I finally came across this piece of code:

```
function get_page_from_line
{
    local nline="$1"
    local input_file="$2"

    local npag=0
    local ln=0
    local total=0

    while IFS= read -d $'\f' -r page; do

        npag=$(( ++npag ))

        ln=$(echo -n "$page" | wc -l)

        total=$(( total + ln ))

        if [ $total -ge $nline ]; then
            echo "${npag}"
            return
        fi

    done < "$input_file"

    echo "0"

    return
}
```

But, unfortunately, this solution proved to be very slow in some cases.

Any better solution ?

Thanks!

Comment: This function could be **translated** in `awk`, give it a try. The performance should be a lot more faster.

Comment: A pure bash version had been added at the top of my answer. This version uses only built-in commands and parameter expansion inside the loops, It seems really faster. Give it a try. The `awk` version is even faster.

Comment: Are the form feeds the only page breaks, or will there be spillover? Traditional teletype would feed a new sheet of paper after approximately 60 lines (depending on paper size etc). Printing on mailing labels would have a record ("page") maximum of 6-10 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea to use `read -d $'\f'` and then to count the lines is good.

This version migth appear not ellegant: if `nline` is greater than or equal to the number of lines in the file, then the file is read twice.

Give it a try, because it is super fast:

```
function get_page_from_line ()
{
    local nline="${1}"
    local input_file="${2}"    
    if [[ $(wc -l "${input_file}" | awk '{print $1}') -lt nline ]] ; then
        printf "0\n"
    else
        printf "%d\n" $(( $(head -n ${nline} "${input_file}" | grep -c "^"$'\f') + 1 ))
    fi
}
```

Performance of **awk** is better than the above bash version. **awk** was created for such text processing.

Give this tested version a try:

```
function get_page_from_line ()
{
  awk -v nline="${1}" '
    BEGIN {
      npag=1;
    }
    {
      if (index($0,"\f")>0) {
        npag++;
      }
      if (NR==nline) {
        print npag;
        linefound=1;
        exit;
      }
    }
    END {
      if (!linefound) {
        print 0;
      }
    }' "${2}"
}
```

When `\f` is encountered, the page number is increased.

`NR` is the current line number.

### ----

For history, there is another bash version.

This version is using only built-it commands to count the lines in current page.

The `speedtest.sh` that you had provided in the comments showed it is a little bit ahead (20 sec approx.) which makes it equivalent to your version:

```
function get_page_from_line ()
{
    local nline="$1"
    local input_file="$2"

    local npag=0
    local total=0

    while IFS= read -d $'\f' -r page; do
        npag=$(( npag + 1 ))
        IFS=$'\n'
        for line in ${page}
        do
            total=$(( total + 1 ))
            if [[ total -eq nline ]] ; then
                printf "%d\n" ${npag}
                unset IFS
                return
            fi
        done
        unset IFS
    done < "$input_file"
    printf "0\n"
    return
}
```

Comment: Your `awk` version is AMAZINGLY FAST! Even when processing *huge* text files (20K pages / 1.3M lines). Clear and readable code.

Comment: Based on @tripleee and @Jay-jargot solutions, I wrote an alternative version: `awk -v FS='\n' -v RS='\f' -v ln="123" 'BEGIN { n = 0 } { n = n + NF - 1; if( n >= ln ) { print NR; found=1; exit; } } END { if(!found ){ print 0; } }' file`

Comment: @lacobus Ofcourse! ha! I should have reworked my own script after having understood your idea in your `bash` version. This new script should be faster than the classic version in my answer, no? This should be visible with `ln` variable set to something greater than the number of lines in the ̀`file` and when the `file` is huge. I wonder what would be the difference mesured with `time` command. (I did not test your awk script, but it seems correct at first read).

Comment: I've measured the processing time of each routine using a test script. The results obtained can be found here: (http://pastebin.com/NTLzFWL7) and the test script used to perform the tests can be found here: (http://pastebin.com/FVw5jhjH).

Comment: @lacobus ouaou! I learnt something tonight. thx! A lot of suprises with `speedtest.sh`. I tested it on the box I am using and the results are comparable to the ones displayed at patebin.com. Suprise I) Replacing command `wc` with a loop and built-in commands is slower. My own ligth tests were different (20x better) with a file with 10000 lines, with short lines. OK, this speedtest.sh
 seems serious. I used to do this trick with great success, in other context. I apply it as a rule (I should not). Surprise II) My awk script is the best in performance. ? !!

Comment: @lacobus after futher tests, it appeared that changing the `if`statement to `if [[ total -eq nline ]] ; then` make my bash version a little bit faster: 20 sec faster approx. over 2m39s, which is weak. But Still the answer had been updated.

Comment: @lacobus got a good one: this new bash version is super fast, equivalent to awk, still slower.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk -v RS='\f' -v n=09 '$0~"^"n"." || $0~"\n"n"." {print NR}' file

3
```

updated anchoring as commented below.

```
 $ for i in $(seq -w 12); do awk -v RS='\f' -v n="$i" 
          '$0~"^"n"." || $0~"\n"n"." {print n,"->",NR}' file; done

01 -> 1
02 -> 1
03 -> 1
04 -> 2
05 -> 2
06 -> 2
07 -> 2
08 -> 2
09 -> 3
10 -> 3
11 -> 3
12 -> 3
```

Comment: Using `RS` seems to collide with `$1`. E.g. `n=10` gives a result only when used with `$3`.

Comment: didn't understand your comment.  There is no third field.

Comment: I tried `awk -v RS='\f' -v n=10 '$1~"^"n"."{print NR}' ` vs `awk -v RS='\f' -v n=10 '$3~"^"n"."{print NR}'`. Only the  second invocation gave me a page number.

Comment: The anchoring `"^"` means that this example only works for first lines in blocks. You'd need to match the newline specifically to get any line.

Comment: Yes, I see now, fixed.

Comment: @karakfa You `awk` script is not working. 1) There is no need to always proccess the file until the last record (or page). When `awk` reach the page that contains the line number, it should print the actual page number (NR) and exit. 2) There is no variable to accumulate the line count (or field count) from each page (or record).

Comment: This `awk` script works fine: `BEGIN { npag=1 } { if( index( $0, "\f" ) > 0 ){ npag++ } if( NR==ln ){ print npag; found = 1; exit; } } END { if( !found ) { print 0; }}`

Comment: lacobus, yes you can exit after print if it's a bottleneck.  You don't need a separate accumulator since NR keeps track of how many records (here pages) there are.

Answer (score 1):

A script of similar length can be written in bash itself to locate and respond to the embedded `<form-feed>`'s contained in a file. (it will work for POSIX shell as well, with substitute for string index and `expr` for math) For example,

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i ln=1     ## line count
declare -i pg=1     ## page count

fname="${1:-/dev/stdin}"            ## read from file or stdin

printf "\nln:pg  text\n"            ## print header

while read -r l; do                 ## read each line
    if [ ${l:0:1} = $'\f' ]; then   ## if form-feed found
        ((pg++))
        printf "<ff>\n%2s:%2s  '%s'\n" "$ln" "$pg" "${l:1}"
    else
        printf "%2s:%2s  '%s'\n" "$ln" "$pg" "$l"
    fi
    ((ln++))
done < "$fname"
```

**Example Input File**

The simple input file with embedded `<form-feed>`'s was create with:

```
$ echo -e "a\nb\nc\n\fd\ne\nf\ng\nh\n\fi\nj\nk\nl" > dat/affex.txt
```

Which when output gives:

```
$ cat dat/affex.txt
a
b
c

d
e
f
g
h

i
j
k
l
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash affex.sh <dat/affex.txt

ln:pg  text
 1: 1  'a'
 2: 1  'b'
 3: 1  'c'
<ff>
 4: 2  'd'
 5: 2  'e'
 6: 2  'f'
 7: 2  'g'
 8: 2  'h'
<ff>
 9: 3  'i'
10: 3  'j'
11: 3  'k'
12: 3  'l'
```

Answer (score 1):

With Awk, you can define `RS` (the record separator, default newline) to form feed (`\f`) and `IFS` (the input field separator, default any sequence of horizontal whitespace) to newline (`\n`) and obtain the number of lines as the number of "fields" in a "record" which is a "page".

The placement of form feeds in your data will produce some empty lines within a page so the counts are off where that happens.

```
awk -F '\n' -v RS='\f' '{ print NF }' file
```

You could reduce the number by one if `$NF == ""`, and perhaps pass in the number of the desired page as a variable:

```
awk -F '\n' -v RS='\f' -v p="2" 'NR==p { print NF - ($NF == "") }' file
```

To obtain the page number for a particular line, just feed `head -n number` to the script, or loop over the numbers until you have accrued the sum of lines.

```
line=1
page=1
for count in $(awk -F '\n' -v RS='\f' '{ print NF - ($NF == "") }' file); do
    old=$line
    ((line += count))
    echo "Lines $old through line are on page $page"
    ((page++)
done
```

Comment: Very interesting approach! Based on your idea I found an alternative solution: `awk -v FS='\n' -v RS='\f' -v ln="123" 'BEGIN { n = 0 } { n = n + NF - 1; if( n >= ln ) { print NR; found=1; exit; } } END { if(!found ){ print 0; } }' file` Thank-you!

Answer (score -1):

This gnu awk script prints the "page" for the linenumber given as command line argument:

```
BEGIN   { ffcount=1;
      search = ARGV[2]
      delete ARGV[2]
      if (!search ) {
        print "Please provide linenumber as argument"  
        exit(1);
      }
    }

$1 ~ search { printf( "line %s is on page %d\n", search, ffcount) }

/[\f]/ { ffcount++ }
```

Use it like `awk -f formfeeds.awk formfeeds.txt 05` where `formfeeds.awk` is the script, `formfeeds.txt` is the file and '05' is a linenumber.

The `BEGIN` rule deals mostly with the command line argument. The other rules are simple rules:

- `$1 ~ search` applies when the first field matches the commandline argument stored in `search`
- `/[\f]/` applies when there is a formfeed

Comment: Please check my last edition. The line numbering was demonstrative.